# Insert Record or Update Record If Exists in Table In One Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, record, sql-insert

My Table

```
member_id - profil_id - A - B - C
1           2           1   0   0
1           3           0   1   0
```

I want to update record for (`member_id=1` and `profil_id=2` and `A=1`)

```
member_id - profil_id - A - B - C
1           2           2   0   0
1           3           0   1   0
```

and again, I want to update record for (`member_id=1` and `profil_id=2` and `A=1`)

```
member_id - profil_id - A - B - C
1           2           3   0   0
1           3           0   1   0
```

I want to insert record for (`member_id=1` and `profil_id=4` and `A=1`)

```
member_id - profil_id - A - B - C
1           2           3   0   0
1           3           0   1   0
1           4           1   0   0
```

and again I want to update record for (`member_id=1` and `profil_id=4` and `C=1`)

```
member_id - profil_id - A - B - C
1           2           3   0   0
1           3           0   1   0
1           4           1   0   1
```

and again I want to update record for (`member_id=1` and `profil_id=4` and `C=1`)

```
member_id - profil_id - A - B - C
1           2           3   0   0
1           3           0   1   0
1           4           1   0   2
```

like this...

thanks..

Comment: It would help if you posted the complete definition of your table. e.g. CREATE TABLE foo (member_id int ...) so I could see all the indexes and such.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this in MySQL. The first is using `REPLACE`. The second is using `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

`REPLACE` will try a delete row, and regardless of success or failure, insert the new row.

`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will try and insert a row and if the insert fails due to a duplicate key on an index error, does an update.